# Drawing balls from an urn with and without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider these two experiments. **Are my considerations on the probability distribution of the labels, $(*)$ and $(**)$ correct?**

**(1)** Put in an urn $N$ balls labelled $v_1,..., v_{N}$; each ball has equal probability to be drawn; draw a ball, let $\tilde{v}_1$ be the label of the drawn ball; put the ball back in the urn; repeat other $k-1$ times, with $k\geq 1$. At the end of the experiment, the drawn labels are $(\tilde{v}_1,..., \tilde{v}_k)$. For example if $N=5$ and $k=3$, we may have as drawn labels $(v_1, v_1, v_5)$.

For $j\in \{1,..., k\}$, we can hence interpret drawn $j$ as the realisation of a random variable $\tilde{V}_j\sim U(\{v_1,..., v_{N}\})$ with $\tilde{V}_j\perp \tilde{V}_h$ $\forall h\neq j \in \{1,..., k\}$.

Equivalently, $(\tilde{V}_1, ..., \tilde{V}_k)\sim U(\mathcal{K})$ where $\mathcal{K}$ denotes the set of all ordered $k$-tuples with possible repetitions from $\{v_1,..., v_N\}$. Notice that $|\mathcal{K}|=N^k$  and $$ (*) \hspace{1cm}\mathbb{P}((\tilde{V}_1, ..., \tilde{V}_k)= (\tilde{v}_1,..., \tilde{v}_k))=\frac{1}{N^k}$$

Is $(*)$ correct?

Now consider the equivalent of (1) but without replacement.

**(2)** Put in an urn $N$ balls labelled $v_1,..., v_{N}$; each ball has equal probability to be drawn; draw a ball, let $\tilde{v}_1$ be the label of the drawn ball; repeat other $k-1$ times, with $1\leq k\leq N$. At the end of the experiment, the drawn labels are $(\tilde{v}'_1,..., \tilde{v}'_k)$. For example if $N=5$ and $k=3$, we may have as drawn labels $(v_1, v_3, v_4)$.

For $j\in \{1,..., k\}$, we can hence interpret the sequence of draws as the realisation of a random vector $(\tilde{V}'_1, ..., \tilde{V}'_k)\sim U(\mathcal{K}')$ where $\mathcal{K}'$ denotes the set of all ordered $k$-tuples without repetitions from $\{v_1,..., v_{V(G)}\}$.

Notice that $|\mathcal{K}'|=\frac{N!}{(N-k)!}$ and 
$$(**) \hspace{1cm}\mathbb{P}((\tilde{V}'_1, ..., \tilde{V}'_k)= (\tilde{v}'_1,..., \tilde{v}'_k))=\frac{(N-k)!}{N!}$$

Is $(**)$ correct?

Comment: It looks over complicated, but essentially yes. $(*)$ is $\frac{1}{N} \times \frac{1}{N} \times \cdots \times \frac{1}{N} = \frac{1}{N^k}$ with replacement, while $(**)$ is $\frac{1}{N} \times \frac{1}{N-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{1}{N-k+1} = \frac{(N-k)!}{N!}$ without replacement

Comment: The notation is confusing and inconsistent. eg: "  the drawn labels are $(\tilde{v}_1,..., \tilde{v}_k)$ ... for example, $k=3$, $(v_1, v_1, v_5)$. Furthermore, I don't get $\tilde{V}_j\perp \tilde{V}_h$